# Files in use after sending multiple attachments via SmtpClient/System.Net.Mail

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, smtpclient, mailmessage, system.net.mail

I have an ASP .Net Core 2.2 Web API.
In it, I have a controller that's used by the front end to send emails.
It's using System.Net.Mail.
I've simplified the code as much as possible:

```
    //POST: api/Email
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
    {
        string attachment1 = Path.Combine(System.AppContext.BaseDirectory, "Attachments", "a.pdf");
        string attachment2 = Path.Combine(System.AppContext.BaseDirectory, "Attachments", "b.pdf");

        using (MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage())
        {
            mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attachment1));
            mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attachment2));                
            mailMessage.To.Add("someone@somehwere.com");

            using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 578))
            {
                smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("me@gmail.com", "12345");
                smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
                await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
            }
        }

        File.Delete(attachment1);
        File.Delete(attachment2);

        return Ok();
    }
```

When I try to delete the attachments, I get the following error:

**Error: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\fabsr\source\repos\PropWorx.API\PropWorx.API\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\Attachments\a.pdf' because it is being used by another process.**

I've tried adding this just before the delete lines:

```
foreach (var attachment in mailMessage.Attachments)
    attachment.Dispose();
```

Even though, from what I've read, disposing the MailMessage will also dispose the attachments. However, it didn't help. Any ideas? Indeed if I try to delete the file from Explorer it also tell me the file is in use. Only once I kill the running project (by hitting the STOP button in Visual Studio) can I then delete the files.

P.s. I haven't tested this on the live server yet... currently I'm testing this on my workstation, running in Debug mode in Visual Studio 2017, if that makes a difference...

Answer (score 1):

Add the attachments during the using

```
  //POST: api/Email
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
    {

        using (MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage())
        {
            mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(@"C:\a.pdf"));
            mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(@"C:\b.pdf"));
            mailMessage.To.Add("someone@somehwere.com");

            using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 578))
            {
                smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("me@gmail.com", "12345");
                smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
                await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
            }
        }

        File.Delete(@"C:\a.pdf");
        File.Delete(@"C:\b.pdf");

        return Ok();
    }
```

Comment: I'm so sorry Daniel, I was actually doing it as you suggested. I simply didn;t post my original question correctly. I've edited the original question to reflect the correct code. Sorry about that!!

Comment: Are you uploading those files as a part of the same process?, probably the problem is in the upload, not in the mailing

Comment: I'm not uploading those files, no. The code I posted is everything that I'm doing. However, I'm wondering if it's got something to do with Visual Studio holding onto the files. Because I've noticed that only once I kill the API (by clicking on the Stop button in Visual Studio) do the files get released and then I can delete them. Perhaps I should publish the API to the server and see if it exhibits the same behavior. Maybe this is all happening because I'm running the project in Debug mode in VS?

Comment: I'm assuming that those files are part of your project and they are generated by the build, then yes, the debugger is locking them, not the mailing

Comment: You can test it even on debug mode, just don't "build" the files, add them manually after start your debugging

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I took the attachments out f the running folder (where the API was running) an now it's fine! Looks like Visual Studio was lockign these files, even though they are not part of my project, and don't even appear in my Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

After reading Daniel's comment, I took the attachments out of the running folder (where the API was running) an now it's fine. It looks like Visual Studio was locking these files, even though they were not part of my project, and didn't even appear in my Solution Explorer.